# Pandas to_sql replace duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I am making request to API every second with parameter since(to return changes since last request) I convert it to dataframe and would like quickly insert it into MySQL with replacement of duplicate rows something like this:

```
REPLACE INTO table (column1,column2...) VALUES (val1,val2...)
```

I really like function [DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) but the problem is that it does not have replace duplicate rows option. The way I can see with DataFrame.to_sql is to drop table each time and recreate it with option if_exists: replace, but I think it will influence performance significantly. Can you advise what is the better way to insert data from dataframe with replacement of duplicate values?

Answer (score 1):

if your DF isn't that big you can iterate through it, generate [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) SQLs and execute them in your MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to replace duplicates with DataFrame.to_sql in pandas. Hopefully they will integrate this function in future. I managed to find a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297817/replacing-duplicates-pandas-to-sql-sqlite) on how to ignore duplicates, but in my case I just decided to choose another approach and as @MaxU mentioned iterate through Dataframe and execute

```
REPLACE INTO table (column1,column2...) VALUES (val1,val2...)
```